# Remove punctuation from list of sentences in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have email messages in a pandas data frame. Before applying **sent_tokenize**, I could **remove the punctuation** like this.

```
def removePunctuation(fullCorpus):
punctuationRemoved = fullCorpus['text'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', '')
return  punctuationRemoved
```

After applying sent_tokenize the data frame looks like below. How can I remove the punctuation while keeping the sentences as tokenized in the lists?

> sent_tokenize

```
def tokenizeSentences(fullCorpus):
sent_tokenized = fullCorpus['body_text'].apply(sent_tokenize)
return sent_tokenized
```

> Sample of data frame after tokenizing into sentences

```
[Nah I don't think he goes to usf, he lives around here though]                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

[Even my brother is not like to speak with me., They treat me like aids patent.]                                                                                                                                                                                                         

[I HAVE A DATE ON SUNDAY WITH WILL!, !]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

[As per your request 'Melle Melle (Oru Minnaminunginte Nurungu Vettam)' has been set as your callertune for all Callers., Press *9 to copy your friends Callertune]                                                                                                                      

[WINNER!!, As a valued network customer you have been selected to receivea £900 prize reward!, To claim call 09061701461., Claim code KL341., Valid 12 hours only.]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with following function where you can use `apply` to iterate over each word in sentence and character and check if character is in punctuation followed by `.join`. Also, you may need `map` since you want to apply function to each sentences:

```
def tokenizeSentences(fullCorpus):
    sent_tokenized = fullCorpus['body_text'].apply(sent_tokenize)
    f = lambda sent: ''.join(ch for w in sent for ch in w 
                                                  if ch not in string.punctuation) 

    sent_tokenized = sent_tokenized.apply(lambda row: list(map(f, row)))    
    return sent_tokenized
```

**Note** you will need `import string` for `string.punctuation`.

Comment: It worked. But removed the comma between sentences also. It looks like ' Even my brother is not like to speak with meThey treat me like aids patent'. How can I keep the sentences separated for later processing?

Comment: Perfect! You saved my time.